# Set default text color when extending Text component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity's Text component has `323232FF` set as color by default. When i extend Text component, that color is not longer set (it's white).

[image]

¿How can i set the default text color when extending the component?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[AddComponentMenu("UI/CodeText", 10)]
public class CodeText : Text
{
    void Awake() {
        Game.Instance.trackMe();
    }
}
```

Unity's Text component source code:

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca5d7dcc97d9974256ef83bc122586/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Text.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default

I'm not overwriting the "GetGenerationSettings" which looks to be setting the color :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two things to consider here:**

1. When you remove and re-add `Text` component from one `GameObject`, its initial color becomes white. That white color is the default value in `Graphic` which `Text` inherits from.
2. This is because invoking hierarchy UI/Text context menu does more than simply adding a `Text` component, it applies a default theme.

Unless you can spot exactly what's done by that hierarchy menu in the sources, you can do the following to set default properties:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[AddComponentMenu("UI/MyText", 10)]
public class MyText : Text
{
    protected override void Awake()
    {
        color = GUI.skin.textField.normal.textColor; // or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty interesting, i didn't think about GUI.skin. So to make it also compatible with customization, i should check if color == white to rewrite it using the default theme as you provided.
`if (color == Color.white) {
            color = GUI.skin.textField.normal.textColor;
        }`

One more thing, that textField color is black and not the `323232FF` :S I remember there was a place in Unity to check GUI skin colors, so i will  make some searches!

Comment: Well, I've put *or whatever* because effectively the color is not the one you were  looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, without diving into the code of Text, that your class isn't calling Text's constructor. Even though you don't define a constructor, your class by default looks like this.

```
public class CodeText : Text
{
    public CodeText() { 
    }

    void Awake() {
        Game.Instance.trackMe();
    }
}
```

What you may need to do is have the constructor call Text's constructor.

```
public class CodeText : Text
{
    public CodeText() : base() { 
    }

    void Awake() {
        Game.Instance.trackMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect, a default empty constructor calling base constructor will be generated by default. By the way, 'constructor' is an evil place to do things in Unity as they're likely to fail (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html).

Comment: @Aybe Or call the Awake in base class, which also isn't being called by the inheriting class.

Comment: You are right, actually I didn't because nowhere in the inheritance chain it is being used.